# Change of Variable Technique help

Tags: statistics

$X$ is a continuous random variable with the pdf $f_X$, and let $Y = X^2$.
Considering the cdf of Y, express the $f_Y(y)$ in terms of $f_X(x)$.

I am confused above transforming $X = \pm \sqrt{Y}$. I only know how to calculate just one side, meaning either just negative value or positive value. How do you calculate both?

Please guide me step by step. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument goes like this:

$$P \left[ Y \leq y \right]= P \left[ X^2 \leq y \right]=P\left[ -\sqrt{y}\leq X \leq \sqrt{y}\right] $$

And now we use the CDF of $X$. Then the last equality can be rewritten as:

$$F_X (\sqrt{y})-F_X (-\sqrt{y})$$

We have the CDF now and since we are dealing with a continuous RV, simple differentiation w.r.t $y$ using the chain rule will do the trick.

Differentiating w.r.t y, then that becomes:

$$f_Y (y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}} f_X (\sqrt{y})+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}f_X (-\sqrt{y})$$

And that is all actually.

If you are to use the Jacobian, you should bear in mind that the transformation is not one-to-one. What we do in those cases is partition the support of $X$ and represent it as a union of two disjoint sets.

To be clear, let the support of $X$ be $S= \{X:-\infty<x<\infty \}$. Then we let $A_1=\{x:-\infty<x<0$ and $A_2=\{x:0\leq x<\infty\}$. Then $S=A_1 \cup A_2$.

Notice that we have two inverse functions, each one corresponding to either $A_1$ or $A_2$, those are $x=-\sqrt{y}$ and $x=\sqrt{y}$. Now the transformations are one-to-one. Denote the support of $Y$ by $T$ and let $B \subset T$. We define $A_3=\{x:x=-\sqrt{y},y \in B \}\subset A_1$ and $A_4=\{x:x=\sqrt{y},y \in B \} \subset A_2$

Therefore

$$P(Y \in B)=P(X \in A_3)+P(X \in A_4)=\int_{A_3} f(x) dx+\int_{A_4} f(x)dx$$

In the first integral let $x=-\sqrt{y}$ and the absolute value of the Jacobian is $1/(2\sqrt{y})$. In the second let $x=\sqrt{y}$ with the same absolute value Jacobian. Therefore:

$$P(Y \in B)= \int _{B} \left[f(-\sqrt{y})+ f(\sqrt{y}) \right]\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$$

The pdf of $Y$ is then the integrand, namely:

$$g(y)=\left[f(-\sqrt{y})+ f(\sqrt{y}) \right]\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\quad y \in T$$

As above. In short, if there are more than one inverse functions never forget to partition the support of $X$. The CDF technique is in my opinion a little easier in such instances.

Comment: Can you help me with Jacobian transformation, please?

Comment: @Takumi I have edited my post to include that technique as well.